# Не удаётся запустить серверное приложение Python3 flask на VPS с CentOS7

Tags: python-3.x, веб-сервер, centos, flask, centos7

Уже третий день пытаюсь запустить своё серверное приложение на VPS под CentOS7. Уже пробую просто **пошагово** воспроизвести вот [эту](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-centos-7) инструкцию.

Проблема возникает на этапе проверки работоспособности. То есть, когда делаю python3 myproject.py
Скрипт запускается, отображается адрес по которому он запустился, в общем всё выглядит так, будто он работает. Но когда иду проверять по адресу сервера, то не отображается страница с hello world. И даже не 404, а просто "не удалось подключиться к серверу".
Пробовал заменять адрес 0.0.0.0 на непосредственно адрес сервера, хотя и с 0.0.0.0 всё вроде как должно работать *(да ведь?)*.

Почему CentOS? Потому что техническое задание такое. Пробовал запускать на Ubuntu просто python3 myproject.py, и всё прекрасно работало. А CentOS мало того что требует использовать virtualenv, так ещё и не работает ничего.
Скорее всего это конечно моя вина, я с CentOS не работал до этого, и вообще с серверными приложениями пару раз только связывался.

Хостер [Vscale](https://vscale.io). Есть промокод SCALE200 на 200 бонусных рублей, этого хватит на месяц VPS с минимальными конфигурациями, так что можете попробовать сами выполнить эту инструкцию.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема не во Flask, а просто порт закрыт брандмуэром.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Сейчас проверю, спасибо за быстрый отклик.

Comment: Какая хитрая реклама хостинга :)

Comment: @andreymal Он действительно не плох на самом деле. Удобный интерфейс и хороший прайс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым, как это обычно и бывает. @SergeyGornostaev сразу угадал в чём беда – брандмауэр.
Отключить его в CentOS можно так:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```